# How does the Attribute Sample Texture node work?? I'm a beginner at Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Okay, I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question but I'll give it my best shot.

I've just started learning Geometry Nodes and today I tried out a course in which I learned how to make grass appear to sway with the wind. In doing so, I used the *Attribute Sample Texture* node.

My question is: What does the "Result" mean? In the picture below, the 4th node from the left, the *Attribute Vector Math* node takes the position attribute, then adds each position vector with another vector.

Here's what I understand: say for example one of the points is [1,1,1] then I add it with [2,4,0] to get a vector [3,5,1]. This new vector is then stored in the custom attribute "mapping". Then I use the mapping attribute in the *Attribute Sample Texture node*... then I'm lost. What happens to each vector? How does a cloud (for example) texture affect the vectors?

Also, I've checked the documentation and I still do not understand: *"The Attribute Sample Texture node evaluates a texture for every point and stores the resulting colors in a new attribute. The mapping attribute can be anything that can be converted to a 3D vector. Typically, either the name of a UV map or the position attribute is used"*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Blender 2.93**

The *Attribute Sample Texture* picks basically an RGB value from the given texture at the given point. The *Mapping* determines how the point in the texture is calculated.

The texture space is going from 0 to 1 by default in the X and Y direction. Then it repeats by default. That is, (0.5, 0.5) is the same as (1.5, 0.5).

In this example, we have an image with the 3 colored letters R, G, B. And a plane with *Geometry* nodes and 5 subdivisions. It's located at (0, 0) the world origin and has a size of 1m x 1m. The *Scale* and *Location* must be applied for the plane (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode)

This way the geometry points are in the range of 0 to 1 for X and Y. Z is always 0. Now we can use the *position* for a 1:1 mapping. The sampled color is separated into *red*, *green*, and *blue* attributes.

The cube for the point instances is scaled along the Z-axis depending on the *red* value. The black cubes have a Z scale value of 0 and are flat like a plane.

[image: example 'R']

If you change the *position* to *UVMap* which is the default name for the UV map then this is used. Open the *UV Editor* and rotate the UV island and you get the following (*blue* is used here):

[image: example 'B']

In your example, the *position* attribute (which is the location of each geometry point) is shifted by a vector (the one with the purple driver) to make them virtually wander around. This shifted position is mapped to the texture and the picked color is stored in the *wind* attribute which is used to rotate the geometry points.

**Update: Blender 3.x and Field Nodes**

[Blender 3.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Nodes_Physics) introduced the [fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) system and many of the 2.9x nodes became legacy nodes. Then in [Blender 3.2](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Nodes_Physics), these old nodes, including the *Attribute Sample Texture* node, have been removed. A replacement is the *Image Texture* node.

Here is example from above in Blender 3.4. It uses the new 3.4 *Sample UV Surface* node to map the image to the points. You need to subdive the default plane first because the node requires geometry with faces.

[image: Blender 3.4 example]

Comment: i dont know why i wasn't notified about this answer, completely missed it. Thank you so much i understand it better now

Comment: The Attribute Sample Texture node was removed from Blender 3 geometry nodes. Do someone knows how to sample textures in GN in Blender 3 instead?

Comment: @ChristophWerner You can use the Image Texture node. The early Blender 3.x versions don't have the *Sample UV Surface* node yet and you probably have to calculate the mapping on your own. In Blender 3.4 and higher, you can use the new *Sample UV Surface* node. I've added an example above.

Comment: @Blunder Thank you a lot! Great hint.